# JAVAFX error incompatible types: FXMLLoader cannot be converted to node

Tags: javafx

I am new to Java and JavaFX. I am trying to develop an CRUD application for employee data. I am adding the FXML file into a tab. The code is as follows.

```
tabEmployee.setContent((Node) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("EmployeeOverview.fxml")));
```

This works fine but when I try to do the same as follows

```
private URL URLEmployeeOverview = getClass().getResource("EmployeeOverview.fxml");
FXMLLoader loaderEmployeeOverview = new FXMLLoader(URLEmployeeOverview);
tabEmployee.setContent((Node) loaderEmployeeOverview);
```

I am getting an error:

> incompatible types. FXMLLoader cannot be converted to Node

May I get help on why this happens and how to correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should invoke the load method:

```
tabEmployee.setContent( (Parent) loaderEmployeeOverview.load() );
```

Comment: Dear Uluk Biy, Thank you. Your answer works. May I get the technical definition?

Comment: @VenkatesanAp, as a name implies `FXMLLoader` is a class for loading fxml files, and you command it to do that by invoking its `load()` method. In other words, if we make an analogy, it is a pencil to draw a picture. It cannot be used as a picture itself. You need to "invoke draw() method" of it.